# struct error "uninitialized reference member"

Tags: c++, struct

im a noob especially in c++.

I have some problems using a struct that i want to use in some functions.

I looked at the other answers here regarding structs in Header files and .cpp but dont realy get it to work.

my .h file:

```
namespace game {

class CPlayer{

        struct GameData{
        int mBoard[8][8];
        CBoard &pBoard;
    };
public:

    CMove Play(const CBoard &pBoard,const CDeadline &pDue);

private:

    int GainsFromMoves(struct GameData gameData);
```

etc.....

then in my .cc file im trying to use this data with:

```
CMove CPlayer::Play(const CBoard &pBoard,const CDeadline &pDue)
{

     GameData gameData;

     gameData.pBoard = pBoard;
```

etc...

where i try to declare the GameData i get an error `uninitialized reference member in ‘struct game::CPlayer::GameData’`

later trying to usethe GainsFromMoves function i also get some error.

```
int GainsFromMoves(GameData gameData){

 int test = 0;

 return test;
}

error: Multiple markers at this line
    - expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
    - ‘GameData’ was not declared in this 
     scope
```

i realize that i probably am doing some really noob error but, i would be very happy for some guidance.

Comment: A reference member must be initialized in [member initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: In general, try to narrow your problems down. This has nothing to do with headers and cc. files, which you would have found out by making a five-line test program to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it's quite possible your code is confused, and that what you are trying to achieve is actually quite a long way from what you have currently. But as a first step I would move the declaration of `GameData` outside of the declaration of `CPlayer`, i.e. `struct GameData { ... }; class CPlayer { ... };`. Is there any reason you declared one inside the other? I would also drop completely `namespace game ...`. At your level of understanding it's just going to make things more complicated without providing any benefit.

Comment: The second error is because compiler does not know the *type*, `GameData`.You need to include the header file which defines `GameData` in the source file where you have defined the function `GainsFromMoves()`.

Comment: I think @juanchopanza advice is good. You need to start again, build up your code slowly, adding tiny bits at a time, making sure it at least compiles as you go. Seems to me you are trying too much too quickly.

Comment: @Als I think he has. I think that specific problem is because he's written a free function when he meant to define the member function. I.e. if he wrote `int CPlayer::GainsFromMoves(GameData gameData) {` it would be OK.

Comment: @john: I doubt that.If that would have been the case the error would be undefined reference to the member function and not `‘GameData’ was not declared in this scope`.Defining a freestanding function would not yield the errors mentioned in the OP.

Comment: There is way too much missing here. Where are `CMove`, `CBoard` and `CDeadline` declared?

Comment: @Als You are missing `GameData` is declared inside `CPlayer`. `int GainsFromMoves(GameData gameData){` does not compile because the compiler is looking for `GameData` in the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first, you need declarations of `CMove`, `CBoard` and `CDeadline`. I added some dummy ones to allow fixing the other problems:

```
namespace game {

struct CBoard {};
struct CDeadline {};
struct CMove {};
...
```

Then, your struct `CPlayer::GameData` needs to intialize it's `CBoard` reference, which should be `const`:

```
class CPlayer{

        struct GameData
        {
          GameData(const CBoard& board) : pBoard(board) {}
          int mBoard[8][8];
          const CBoard &pBoard;
        };
public:
    CMove Play(const CBoard &pBoard,const CDeadline &pDue);
private:
    int GainsFromMoves(struct GameData gameData);
};
```

Next, in your `.cc` file, you need the namespace as well as the class name when defining member functions:

```
namespace game
{
CMove CPlayer::Play(const CBoard &pBoard,const CDeadline &pDue)
{
     GameData gameData(pBoard);
     return CMove();
}
int CPlayer::GainsFromMoves(GameData gameData){

  int test = 0;

 return test;
}

} // namespace game
```

This gets rid of the errors, at least with this simple main:

```
int main()
{
  game::CBoard b;
  game::CDeadline d;
  game::CPlayer p;
  p.Play(b, d);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that his design is basically correct, and all that the OP needs is advice with the technical aspects of implementing it. I'm not sure that is correct. But a very useful answer if it's what the OP needs.

Comment: @john You are right, I am not going into the design at all. I think there isn't enough information in the question yet. A lot of the code I posted is just dummy code to make things compile.

Comment: Thanks that helped but im still at square one(the reason i started all this mess with struct)


When writing like you it works in my play function but in my GainsFromMoves i get errors.


so in the header it is:     


int GainsFromMoves(struct GameData gameData);


in the .cc file its: 


int GainsFromMoves(GameData gameData)


but then i get the following :


Multiple markers at this line

 - ‘GameData’ was not declared in this 
  scope


 - expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token


 - Type 'GameData' could not be resolved

Comment: Hmm well moved the struct to declare it in the .cc file, combined with some of your help it made it compile at least, now i will try to see if it works as well. Again thanks